# Loop through an array in jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops

How can I loop through this **$user** array in jQuery? If 'Failure' returned then error should be printed.

[Solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326820/how-to-print-json-data) actually prints it but with this output which is wrong: **undefinedadmin_1,admin_2,admin_3**

Thanks in advance

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];

if($id == 1)
{
    $users['data'] = array(array('name'=> 'admin_1'), array('name'=> 'admin_2'), array('name'=> 'admin_2'));
    echo json_encode($users);
}
else
{
    $users['data'] = 'Failure';
    echo json_encode($users);
}
?>



$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'list.php',
    data        : 'id=' + text_id,
    dataType    : 'json',
    success     : function(response)
    {
        //IF not 'Failure', loop through the array and print content into div.success
        //IF 'Failure', show div.fail
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(response.data == 'Failure') {
    console.log('error');
    return false;
}

for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    if(typeof response.data[i].name != 'undefined') {
        console.log(response.data[i].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to store names in a variable and print it afterwards but **result = result+response.data[i].name  + ', ';** prints it like this: undefinedadmin_1,admin_2,admin_3

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($.isArray(response)) {
    //loop through array
} else {
    //show error
}
```